# How are the " free fall" formulation and the " accelerated rocket" formulation of the (Weak) Equivalence Principle related? (General Relativity)

Tags: general-relativity, equivalence-principle

This question pertains to a very basic level of understanding of Einstein's theory; my formulation of the equivalence principle does not aim at technical accuracy (in particular it ignores the problem of tidal forces).

---

This picture illustrates two common ways of stating the (Weak) Equivalence Principle on which rests Einstein's General Theory of Relativity.

[image]

(Source DrPhysicsA's channel): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MkYpif7kNGM

Each formulation is rather intuitive:

1. being in free fall is equivalent to being freed from gravity; a person in a box in free fall could not perform any experiment proving that she is not in a region of space where no gravitational force exists (and hence, in an inertial frame)
2. being acted upon by a gravitational force is equivalent to being accelerated upwards, in a way that a person on a box at the surface of the earth could not perform any experiment proving that she is not in a rocket constantly accelerated upwards (at rate $g$).

My question is not as to how to explain each formulation  taken separately, but as to **how to explain the equivalence of the two formulations**.

More precisely: if the most basic and fondamental formulation is the second one ( this is the one I find in Lambourne for example), ***how to show that the first is equivalent to the second***?

Also, if these two formulations present 2 different aspects of the principle, why is it worth distinguising these two aspects, and what theoretical role will play each aspect in the theory, in terms of consequences that can be drawn from them?

Answer (score 2):

The underlying physics that connects the formulations 1) and 2)  is equivalence of inertial mass and gravitational mass.

There is strong corroborating evidence for that equivalence (versions of the [Eötvös experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment) have pushed the accuracy of the verification to 1 in hundred million, according to the wikipedia article).

In the scientific community the general consensus is: given the available evidence the equivalence is beyond reasonable doubt.